# Не могу обратиться к объекту по индексу

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Нужно реализовать в программе на Pascal ABC.NET класс одномерный массив и унаследовать от него двумерный массив. Для двумерного массива перегрузил операцию [] через индексное свойство. Но при попытке обратиться к массиву через [] выдает ошибку:
"Property reference with invalid number of arguments". Как исправить

```
program Lab3;

{ Класс массив (одномерный статический) }
type
Mas = class
protected
    intList: array of integer;   // Список значений
    n: integer;
    procedure setValue(index: integer; val: integer);  // Присвоение значения index-му элементу
    begin
        if index >= Self.n then
        begin
            writeln(' Index out of range ');
            exit;
        end;
        intList[index] := val;
    end;

    function getValue(index: integer): integer;  // чтение элемента с индексом index
    begin
        if index >= Self.n then
        begin
            writeln(' Index out of range ');
            exit;
        end;
        Result := intList[index];
    end;

public
     constructor (const size: integer);                 // Создание массива
     begin
         intList := new integer[size];
         Self.n := size;
     end;

     property Val[i: integer]: integer read getValue write setValue; default;  // Переопределение метода []
end;

Mas2D = class(Mas)
private
    m: integer;

    procedure setValue2(i, j, val: integer);
    begin
        var index: integer := i*Self.n+j;
        if index >= Self.n*Self.m then
        begin
            writeln(' Index out of range ');
            exit;
        end;
        intList[index] := val;
    end;

    function getValue2(i, j: integer): integer;
    begin
        var index: integer := i*Self.n+j;
        if index >= Self.n*Self.m then
        begin
            writeln(' Index out of range ');
            exit;
        end;
        Result := intList[index];
    end;

public
    constructor (const n, m: integer);
    begin
        intList := new integer[n*m];
    end;

    property Val2[i, j: integer]: integer read getValue2 write setValue2;  // Переопределение метода []
end;


var myArray: Mas;
var a, b: integer;
begin
    a := 4;
    b := 4;
    myArray := new Mas2D(a, b);

    for var i:=0 to a-1 do
        for var j:=0 to b-1 do
            myArray[i, j] := 3;   // Вот тут ошибка

    for var i:=0 to a-1 do
    begin
        for var j:=0 to b-1 do
            write(myArray[i, j], '  ');
        writeln(' ');
    end;
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Кроме прочего, у вас индексное свойство Val с одним аргументом было определено как дефолтное, поэтому при обращении требовало 1 параметр, а вы передавали 2. Я переопределил свойство Val с двумя аргументами и сделал дефолтным его. Также заменил тип myArray с Mas на Mas2D, применил вызов унаследованного конструктора и задействовал переменную m.

```
program Lab3;

{ Класс массив (одномерный статический) }
type
Mas = class
protected
    intList: array of integer;   // Список значений
    n: integer;
    procedure setValue(index: integer; val: integer);  // Присвоение значения index-му элементу
    begin
        if index >= Self.n then
        begin
            writeln(' Index out of range ');
            exit;
        end;
        intList[index] := val;
    end;

    function getValue(index: integer): integer;  // чтение элемента с индексом index
    begin
        if index >= Self.n then
        begin
            writeln(' Index out of range ');
            exit;
        end;
        Result := intList[index];
    end;

public
     constructor Create(const size: integer);                 // Создание массива
     begin
         intList := new integer[size];
         Self.n := size;
     end;

     property Val[i: integer]: integer read getValue write setValue;  // Переопределение метода []
end;

Mas2D = class(Mas)
private
    m: integer;

    procedure setValue(i, j, v: integer);
    begin
        var index: integer := i*Self.n+j;
        if index >= Self.n*Self.m then
        begin
            writeln(' Index out of range ');
            exit;
        end;
        intList[index] := v;
    end;

    function getValue(i, j: integer): integer;
    begin
        var index: integer := i*Self.n+j;
        if index >= Self.n*Self.m then
        begin
            writeln(' Index out of range ');
            exit;
        end;
        Result := intList[index];
    end;

public
    constructor Create(const n, m: integer);
    begin
        inherited Create(n*m);
        Self.m := m;
        Self.n := n;
    end;

    property Val[i, j: integer]: integer read getValue write setValue; default; // Переопределение метода []
end;


var myArray: Mas2D;
var a, b: integer;
begin
    a := 4;
    b := 4;
    myArray := new Mas2D(a, b);

    for var i:=0 to a-1 do
        for var j:=0 to b-1 do
            myArray[i, j] := 3;   

    for var i:=0 to a-1 do
    begin
        for var j:=0 to b-1 do
            write(myArray[i, j], '  ');
        writeln(' ');
    end;
end.
```

```
3  3  3  3   
3  3  3  3   
3  3  3  3   
3  3  3  3
```